# How to format sentences with punctuations in pig latin python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

As the title says, we have to format sentences into pig latin and have the punctuations considered. I am struggling to get it working.

What I've done so far:

```
user_input = input('Enter a Sentence: ').lower()
words = user_input.split()
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

for x, word in enumerate(words):
if word[0] in vowels:
    words[x] = words[x]+ "way"

else:
    has_vowel = False
    
    for y, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter in vowels:
            words[x] = word[y:] + word[:y] + "ay"
            has_vowel = True
            break
    if(has_vowel == False):
        words[x] = words[x]+ "ay"

pig_latin = ' '.join(words)
print("Pig Latin: ",pig_latin)
```

desired output:

```
IN: egg!
OUT: eggway!
```

output I get:

```
IN: egg!
OUT: egg!way
```

What I've tried to do:

```
# Add a list of punctuations
punct_list = ["!", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", ";", ":", "'", '"', "?", "/", "\\", "*", "<", ">", "-", "@", "^", "&", "_", ",", "~", "#", "%", ".", "$", "`"]

# Add an elif
elif word[-1] in punct_list:
    words[x] = words[x:-1] + "way" + words[-1]
```

However, this returns an error that a "str" and "list" could not be concatenated. I am lost, also, I do believe we are not allowed to use any modules. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just add a condition `if word[-1] in punct_list:` `word = word[:-1] + "way" + word[-1]`

Comment: This works, but the succeeding word with the first letter being a vowel gets messed up.

Comment: Well, you have to take that in account. make a case when the word starts with a vowel and ends in a punctuation mark.

Comment: I did try to take that into account by doing this: `if word[0] and word[-1] in combined_list:` `words[x] = word[:-1] + "way" + word[-1]`  `IN: aight, imma head out, Charlie!`  `OUT: aightway, immwaya eadhay outway, arliechay!` Why is it immwaya rather than immaway? Am I doing something wrong? combined_list has both punctuations and vowels.

Comment: you have ran a debugger and checked line by line the code right?

Comment: Yes, I've run it, and didn't show anything unusual. It's only now working for the next word with a vowel as its first letter.

Comment: so you didn't find anything unusual in `if word[0] and word[-1] in combined_list` ? this will give you always true, since you are basically doing `if bool(word[0]) == True and word[-1] in combined_list`

Comment: shouldn't it be both True?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve your problem using built in `re` module

The main idea of `main` function is to split sentence on words, make each word pigified and to substitute initial words on pigified one

```
import re


def main():
    sentence = 'pig latin, eat banana! will butler?'

    for word in re.findall(r'\w+', sentence):
        pig_word = pigify(word)
        sentence = re.sub(word, pig_word, sentence)

    return sentence


def pigify(word):
    result = ''
    if word[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        result = word+'way'
    else:
        result = word[1:]+word[0]+'ay'
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = main()
    print(x)
```

NOTE: You can rewrite pigify function if you are not satisfied with my algorithm

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is really helpful, however, we are not allowed to use any modules, may it be built-in or not. While I do understand what you did, I don't think our professor will accept this kind of answer. Still, thank you so much for answering.